# com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException for *.json.swp?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a JSON file that i want to deserialize by Jackson `ObjectMapper`

```
    private static ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

    ...
    Foo foo1 = objectMapper.readValue(file, Foo.class);
```

the JSON file is valid(used a lint checker thing). the json file name looks like:

`foo_(baz)_qux_-bar-quuz-corg-thud.json`

the stack trace looks like:

```
   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'b0VIM': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
     at [Source: .../.foo_(baz)_qux_-bar-quuz-corg-thud.json.swp; line: 1, column: 7]
   [testng]     at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1702)
    ...
```

why is it saying it's having trouble with a token in the swap file? and the String `b0VIM` is not anywhere in the .json file. could the "(" be throwing it off?

what could I be missing?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to de-serialize a **VIM Swap file**.
Usually those temporary files, which contains metadata on what you changed inside a file with the VIM editor, starts with `b0VIM` ([docs](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/doc/recover.txt)).

Swap files have the `.swp` extension, and in fact the file name is

```
foo_(baz)_qux_-bar-quuz-corg-thud.json.swp
```

**Swap files do not contain valid JSON.**

Comment: Thanks! I completely missed the fact that I was going through a folder, and I forgot to validate if the files were json file not not